# how to convert from ascii code to normal code in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, ascii

hi guys i want to convert from ascii code to normal code 
cause i made a method that converts from normal code to ascii code and i want to revers it
here is my method to convert to ascii

```
public string CreatSerial()
    {
        string serial = "";
        string P1, P2 = "";
        string Befor_Serial = GetDeviceSerial().Trim() + 5;
        P1 = Befor_Serial.Substring(0, Befor_Serial.Length / 2);
        P2 = Befor_Serial.Substring(Befor_Serial.Length / 2);
        Befor_Serial = P2 + "ICS" + P1;
        char[] strarr = Befor_Serial.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(strarr);
        serial = new string(strarr);
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serial);
        serial = "";
        foreach (byte b in asciiBytes)
        {
            serial += b.ToString();
        }
        return serial;
    }
```

Comment: Not merely a duplicate but practically the same title, down to the word "normal". Surprised it didn't turn up in the search you performed before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are creating is irreversible.
Look at this example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/xd12z8ts.aspx)

```
byte[] bytes = {0, 1, 14, 168, 255};
foreach (byte byteValue in bytes)
   Console.WriteLine(byteValue.ToString());
// The example displays the following output to the console if the current
// culture is en-US:
//       0
//       1
//       14
//       168
//       255
```

If you put this numbers together you will get `0114168255`. No way you can get bytes back from it. What you can do is to use `Byte.ToString("x")` instead. It will produce hexadecimal representation of the underlying byte value. It will be always of lenght 2.